# CRR Failures - recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does AWS provide any mechanism to monitor and recover from cross region replication failures ? or is this something that needs to be handled using additional coding ( using lambda to copy from bucket on one region to another for example )

Comment: Cross-Region Replication is eventually consistent. It should work automatically but might take (could be seconds or minutes) to copy the content.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein . Doesn’t it mean that there is 0% chance of CRR failing permanently for any given file ?